# SASS install error - ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: sass, rubygems, installation

I recieve the following error when trying to install sass? Anyone know have I can resolve this error?

```
iMac:~ User$ sudo gem install sass
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
iMac:~ User$
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```